# MS project. Shared tasks

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, tasks

What if a task takes 10 days to complete, of which person A works 10 weeks and person B only helps the last 2 weeks? 
I can choose that person B works 20%, but project plans other activities in person Bs spare time on all 10 weeks, it does not get that he only helps the last 2 weeks.

Do I need to create a new task for person B? For the last 2 weeks? Or is there a smart way to incorperate this in the already existing task?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on (1) your confidence in the stability of the plan and (2) your available time to create and refine the plan and (3) how far in the future the work activities will occur and (4) if the work is on your project's critical chain of activities.

If you have the time and are confident that the plan is stable, then create a separate task and use either a finish-to-start relationship or a finish-to-finish relationship.

If you don't have a lot of time, but these tasks are on the critical chain of your project, then it might be a good idea to put in the detail so that your resource plan is valid.

If you aren't confident in the stability of the plan and the activities won't happen for a while, then consider creating a placeholder task C that is duration A + B and uses both resources. When you get close to performing the work (2-4 weeks in advance) and there is less uncertainty, then replace C with A and B. This approach will help minimize the wasted effort of re-planning, especially important if re-planning will involve participation from the team and take them away from doing the work.

Answer (score 1):

You can delay a resource's work on a task by using the Task Form. (Split from a Gantt view). Assign Resource A - Project will calculate 400 hours of work.  Assign Resource B, manually entering 80 hour of work. (2 weeks).  Change the format of the Task Form (use the Task Form Tools Format Ribbon) to Schedule.  Add 8 weeks in the delay field for Resource Bs assignment.